# Using GetMethodID two times at c++

Tags: java, c++, jar, jvm, java-native-interface

I am trying to call 2 different methods at java from c++ by using JNI

my c++ code is:

```
int main()

{  
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    JavaVMOption options;

    options.optionString="-Djava.class.path=try5.jar";

    vm_args.version=JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions=1;
    vm_args.options=&options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized=0;
    int ret=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void**)&env,&vm_args);

    jclass cls1=env->FindClass("hilla1");
    jclass cls=reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(cls1));
    jmethodID constract=env->GetMethodID(cls1,"<init>","()V");
    jobject localobj=env->NewObject(cls,constract);
    jobject instance=env->NewGlobalRef(localobj);

    jclass input = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    char* str="hilla";

    jstring string1=env->NewStringUTF(str);

    int input2[2]={5,4};
    jintArray args=(jintArray)env->NewIntArray(2);
    int *input1=input2;
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(args,0,2,(jint*)input1);

 jmethodID meth = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main1", "([ILjava/lang/String;)V"); 
 env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls,meth,args,string1);

 jmethodID meth1= env->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"main2","(I;)[I");


    return 1;}
```

when I call main1 it's works, but when I call main2 it's give me meth1=0 (GetMethodsID failed)

main2 is:

```
public static int[] main2(int b)
```

Comment: You should *always* use `javap` to get method signature strings. Don't try to make them up yourself when there's a tool provided.

Answer (score 0):

You want `"(I)[I`" not `"(I;)[I`". (The semicolon is only needed after L.)

I believe there's a tool (javap) that will generate these signatures for you; otherwise they can be quite annoying.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45>javap -s -classpath myJar.jar com.package.MyClass
    Compiled from "MyClass.java"
   public class com.package.MyClass extends java.lang.Object{
       public com.package.MyClass();
         Signature: ()V
       public void setStuff(com.package.Stuff);
          Signature: (Lcom/package/Stuff;)V
    }
```

`javap` is very useful but to focus on one method, try:

```
javap -s -public java.lang.String | egrep -A 2 "getBytes"
```

(If you need `egrep` on Windows, you can install [GOW](http://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow).)

Comment: Thanks to the person who suggested javap in an edit - which unfortunately now seems to have vanished.

Comment: Yeah, no clue how that happened.  :[

Comment: @Samhain Your edit was rejected (not by me). Probably better as a comment or a different answer. But I've added it myself and marked the answer as community wiki. Thanks for the input.